# Set certificate postman

Tags: certificate, api

I have to test a collection of APIs on postman and I have been given two files related to the certificate. One file with the extension KEY and another with the extension. CER. I noticed that a file with the CRT extension is required on postman. Is it correct to rename the CER file with the CRT extension?

Answer (score 0):

> "One [CER] is a "binary" X.509 encoding, and the other [CRT] is a "text" base64 encoding that usually starts with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----". These encode the same data but in different ways. Most systems accept both formats, but, if you need to, you can convert one to the other via openssl or other tools. The encoding within a certificate file is really independent of which extension somebody gave the file"

Snippet from the accepted answer on stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642284/do-i-need-to-convert-cer-to-crt-for-apache-ssl-certificates-if-so-how

Per the above quote, you would need to convert the CER file to CRT file. This can be done using the openssl cli tool. Sample command provided.

`openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt`

Snippet from an answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642284/do-i-need-to-convert-cer-to-crt-for-apache-ssl-certificates-if-so-how